# sign-in problem in windows due to repeated shoutdown

Tags: windows, passwords

When I first submit password first time in that day power on my laptop I shows to wait 2 hours. After more than 10 hours it's not sorted. What should I do know I looked many others resource in Internet it not worked I am new to Windows can anybody help me.

I tried troubleshooting startup and password recovery. And Microsoft code bot receiving to my Gmail.